# Ternary operator with returns of different length

Tags: python, conditional-operator

Under python3.9, `(1,0) if False else 1` resolves to `1` as one would expect. However, `1,0 if False else 1` (i.e., the above without parentheses) resolves to `(1,1)`. Why is this happening?

Note that the same does not occur if one rewrites the expression as an if: [...] else, i.e.

```
if False:
   1,0
else:
   1
```

resolves to `1` as expected.

Comment: Statement after the comma is evaluated, so python evaluates `0 if False else 1` and gives 1 which is then packed with 1 into the tuple (1,1).

Comment: Example to understand `print(1,0 if False else 1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Operator precedence

`1,0 if False else 1` is equivalent to `1, (0 if False else 1)`